# Getting dynamic src of an image

Tags: python, urllib

I hava an `<img />` which src attribute is being set by javascript script dynamically - so it would be `<img src="http://1.2.3.4/some_image.jpg?m=3681368312" />` now, and a second later `<img src="http://1.2.3.4/some_image.jpg?m=1234234" />`. I want to use python to load this image and save it. Problem is that when I load the html, src attribute is empty - it's set later, so when I load it I get `<img src="" />`. Second problem is that the IP part of the address may vary over time. I want my solution to be generic and not having to change my code when something on the provider's side would change is a must. Is there a way to load this dynamically changing content?

EDIT:

Of course I know, I can reverse engineer the javascript behavior - parse js script, get currently loaded ip and generate random token, but I would like to avoid this...

Comment: You cannot avoid it; you have to use *something* that executes the JS code, or reverse engineer what the JS code does and do that yourself in Python (at which point it is no longer generic).

Comment: That something could be a full browserstack connected to Python, such as [`Ghost.py`](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) would provide.

Comment: I knew that python had everything, but that's just so cool :D. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 'src' or your 'img' without reverse engineering the javascript you have to execute it in a "browser".

In python, for this, I use PyQt4 (QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit)

Here is an example : https://github.com/JulienPalard/PyWebScrap